# How can I set the size of JButton in an Applet?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jbutton, japplet

I have an applet and I want to add a jbutton. The problem is the button is too big, I already used the setSize() method but still it doesn't work. Perhaps the setting of setSize could might be wrong.

could someone got an idea about this problem?

Thanks...

```
private JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
private JButton players = new JButton("Players");
private JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");

public void init()

{

    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400, 400);
    content.add(newGame);
    content.add(players);
    content.add(quit);

}
```

Comment: [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Did you read the tutorial yet? Did you look at the layout manager that displays buttons in a row?

Comment: It is best to add components and panels to a single panel, then either add the panel to the content pane, or set it as the content pane.  That way the GUI can be reused for, or adapted to, a frame, applet, window, dialog, option pane, one part of another layout, a tab in a tabbed pane, a card in a card layout..

Comment: `Applet.setSize(400, 400);`  Don't call that.  An applet's size is set in the HTML (or can be changed using JavaScript).  Calling that method from within an applet will cause 'strange and unpredictable' behavior.  Results will vary in different versions of different browsers on different OS' using different versions (and suppliers) of Java VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the layout manager you are using for your container (panel, frame, applet..). This plays a major role in defining the size & position of components (like `JButton`).

See also in the Java Tutorial for more details:

- [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).
- The [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson.

Comment: I used only applet, it is necessary to use frame?

Comment: not necessarily.. your applet does the job of displaying things.. its important to use the correct LayoutManager, if you are using an IDE (like netbeans) designing would be a lot easier if not please refer to this link to get an idea as to how to choose a layoutmanager .http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: @Anantha  Part of your comment is so good I edited it into the answer.  Didn't like the bit about 'use IDE'.  ;)

Comment: @Anantha i'm not using netbeans, im using IntelliJ IDEA. You can see it in my tags but anyways, tnx for that info. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add JPanel into your applet and then add JButton to it

The tree code conception is

**JApplet (GridLayout) <- JPanel (FlowLayout) <- JButton (setSize(new Dimension(x,y)))**

---

Good Luck